# What is scoped-proxy in spring configuration

Tags: spring

In the applicaiton-context file I found the below line

.

I searched in google and unable to get exactly what is mean by scoped-proxy="targetClass".  Could anybody let me know what this refers exactly

Answer (score 0):

Please read below extract from Spring reference 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf

@Scope and scoped-proxy
Spring offers a convenient way of working with scoped dependencies through scoped proxies. The
easiest way to create such a proxy when using the XML configuration is the  element. Configuring your beans in Java with a @Scope annotation offers equivalent support with
the proxyMode attribute. The default is no proxy ( ScopedProxyMode.NO), but you can specify
ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS or ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES.